# aspnet webapi method that takes Project/42/Children - how?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I can't figure out how to write the method signature for a REST(ish) AJAX call in Aspnet WebAPI.
My route is recognised but I get a "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI..."

I try to do a REST(ish) call like

```
http://mysite.com/api/Project/42/Children
```

and my idea is to have the server return all children of project 42.

My route is:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/Children",
    defaults: new { action="Children"}
);
```

and my method signature is:

```
public class ProjectController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Project> Children(int projectID) {
    ...
```

Why isn't my method recognised?
I am also not sure I am doing the right "restish" thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your action parameter name from 'proejctID' to 'id'

public IEnumerable Children(int **id**)